# Is it possible to use another menu as a submenu of a menu?

Tags: 7, routes

Is there a setting or a module, this would facilitate re-use of menus...

For example:

```
Menu 1
  option A
  option B
  option C
  option D

Menu 2
  option 1
  option 2
  option 3 
  option 4

Full Main Menu
  option A (use menu 2 for sub menu options)
    option 1
    option 2
    option 3 
    option 4
  option B
  option C
  option D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, the closest existing solution appears to be [Advanced Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_menu):

From the [Advanced Menu module project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_menu):

> **Sub-Menus with Menu Merge (7.x-1.3+)**
>
> Menus can now be merged into
>   other menus. This allows users with the appropriate permission to add
>   links to other menus which are then displayed as if there were a
>   single menu.

Answer (score 1):

There are not settings I am aware. I have not done an exahaustive search for a module. However, you could write your own implementation with a custom module implementing [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7). Simply put, you would create a new menu. Then, you would iterate through the other menu's in your implementation adding each element to the new menu.

Comment: +1 thanks for this @Brandon Bearden it's certainly an option if the Advanced Menu module would not be suited (though I can't think of a scenario at the moment)